# Spark: .saveAsTextFile losing inherited field for the Java object

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, apache-spark, derived-class

I have the following classes:

```
public final class Derived extends AbstractBase implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String fieldA
       :
}

public abstract class AbstractBase {

    protected List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();

    public final String toJsonString() {
        return (new Gson()).toJson(this);
    }

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return toJsonString();
    }

    :
}
```

Then in my Spark job:

```
 val myRDD: RDD[Derived] = input.map {
     ...
 }.saveAsTextFile("myOutput")
```

The Json string of each `Derived` object in myOutput file is always missing the `sources` list. However, if I manually move

```
protected List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
```

from `AbstractBase` to `Derived` class, everything works fine.

Does anyone know why an inherited field is missing during the Spark - saveAsTextfile method?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a reproducer? I don't think it's an issue of `saveAsTextFile`. You can use `collect().foreach(println)` to check if it outputs the same result.

Answer (score 1):

When writing the `RDD` as text file it won't use Java serialization but only call `toString` on every record. See example:

```
case class A (i:Int,s:String) extends Serializable { override def toString = "po"}
val r = sc.parallelize(Seq( A(1,"a"), A(2,"b")))
r.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/f2")
 // hadoop fs -cat /tmp/f2/part* will give "po","po"
 // same but no overriding toString
case class B (i:Int,s:String) extends Serializable
val r = sc.parallelize(Seq( A(1,"a"), A(2,"b")))
r.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/f2")
// result B(1,a) B(2,b)
```

Note that it will use Java serialization if you use `saveAsObjectFile` but that format is not very friendly for non-java programs and comes with its own drawbacks (it's slower and takes more space then Kryo, for instance)